# looping through directories and remove files

Tags: bash, shell

I want to Loop through the homefolders and validate, if the path /home/*/.ssh/authorized_keys exists. If it exists, I want to remove the file .../.ssh/disabled_authorized_keys for the user, that has already the authorized_keys file in his homefolder.

I have created this script so far, but it will remove all disabled_authorized_keys and not just for the users who have the authorized_keys.

```
 for i in /home/*/.ssh/authorized_keys;
 do ii=`echo $i|awk -F '/' '{print $3}'` ;
 rm /home/$ii/.ssh/disabled_authorized_keys;
 done
```

Thank you in advance. (I'm an absolute beginner in bash scripting!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for path in /home/*/.ssh/authorized_keys; do
    rm "$(dirname "$path")"/disabled_authorized_keys
done
```

It will grumble on stderr if `disabled_authorized_keys` does not exists, but will not "crash".

[More about `dirname`](https://ss64.com/bash/dirname.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
for dir in /home/*/.ssh; do
    [[ -e $dir/authorized_keys ]] && rm "$dir/disabled_authorized_keys"
done
```

`[[ -e file ]]` checks if `file` exists. Read `&&` as "if-then".

Comment: This was my first try; however it only worked if executed directly in the bash console but not with the prefix shell: ... in a .yml file.